# Mac Simulator (Xcode) wait for startup command

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, simulator

In Android I can run this to start emulator

```
emulator @NAME
```

and this to wait for it to load completely and be ready to use

```
adb wait-for-device
```

Is there an equivalent for iOS Simulator on Mac? I use default Xcode Simulator. So start of simulator

```
xcrun simctl boot deviceID
```

and wait for it to load completely (*just an example of what I'm thinking of*)

```
xcrun simctl wait deviceId
```

Comment: I am puzzled over the same problem. Did you solve it? I think the solution might be simply wait for the process to finish.

Comment: I didn't solve it. I made a workaround and still waiting for a reply. Currently I am just sleeping for 2 minutes (test VM is slow as heck). Not most efficient but works

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a not-exactly-documented simctl command of `xcrun simctl bootstatus deviceID`

It doesn't appear in the normal output of `xcrun simctl help`, but it does have `xcrun simctl help bootstatus`

From my own playing with it, if you call it, when the bootstatus command exits, your simulator should be fully operational. But since it isn't exactly documented your mileage may vary.

```
xcrun simctl help bootstatus
Checks device boot status.
Usage: simctl bootstatus <device> [-bc]
    -b       Boot the device if it isn't already booted.
    -c       Continuously monitor boot status through multiple boot/shutdown cycles.

Monitors the specified device and prints boot status information until the device finishes booting. You can safely call this before you attempt to start booting the device.
```

```
/usr/bin/xcrun simctl bootstatus 88668721-0DF0-4167-8F3E-37190E8099C1
Monitoring boot status for AutomationDevice - iPad Air 2 - iOS 11.4 (88668721-0DF0-4167-8F3E-37190E8099C1).
[2019-05-23 03:50:56 +0000] Status=2, isTerminal=NO, Elapsed=00:00.
    Waiting on Data Migration
        Reason:(null)
        Migration Elapsed:00:00 seconds

[2019-05-23 03:50:56 +0000] Status=2, isTerminal=NO, Elapsed=00:01.
    Waiting on Data Migration
        Reason:Running plugin com.apple.MobileContainerManager.ContainerMigrator (ContainerMigrator.migrator, user-agnostic)
        Migration Elapsed:00:00 seconds

[spaaaaaaam...]

[2019-05-23 03:51:06 +0000] Status=2, isTerminal=NO, Elapsed=00:11.
    Waiting on Data Migration
        Reason:Running plugin com.apple.iTunesStore.migrator (iTunesStore.migrator)
        Migration Elapsed:00:10 seconds

[2019-05-23 03:51:08 +0000] Status=1, isTerminal=NO, Elapsed=00:12.
    Waiting on BackBoard

[2019-05-23 03:51:12 +0000] Status=4, isTerminal=NO, Elapsed=00:16.
    Waiting on System App

[2019-05-23 03:51:12 +0000] Status=4294967295, isTerminal=YES, Elapsed=00:17.
    Finished
```

Comment: Perfecto! I was waiting for throwaway ("loose") time at work to take a look on this and I'm surprised  how on point it is.

For future reference and copy paste material: you can run `xcrun simctl boot deviceID` to start device and `xcrun simctl bootstatus deviceID` directly after, you'll be prompted stuff in @Aaron answer and next line will be executed only after `Status=4294967295, isTerminal=YES,` is displayed. Loop AVD/Simulator devices start & test automation is easy now!

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer which works great for me. I am using `"xcrun simctl spawn <UDID> launchctl print system | grep com.apple.springboard.services"` and looking for these values in the output:

```
"M   A   com.apple.springboard.services"
"U   A   com.apple.backboardd"
"M   D   com.apple.medialibraryd"
"M   A   com.apple.mobile.installd"
```